# How do I get the last SQL query performed by ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking for something like CodeIgniter's:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

(http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't think this is simple - you'd probably have to modify ActiveRecord somewhere. I'm also concerned that such an action would break the (admittedly leaky) abstraction. There may be a better, more Rails-friendly way to achieve what you wnat to do.

Comment: I wanted to log queries while the Rails/ActiveRecord log level is set low, so I'd only see queries that I'm really interested in.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no easy way to access the list of queries. Nonetheless you can easily get access to them creating a super simple logger.

If you open the class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter` you'll see a method called log. This method is invoked on each query to log the statement. By default, it logs all the statements with the Rails logger.

You can do something like

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter.class_eval do

  attr_reader :last_query
  alias_method_chain :log, :last_query

  def log_with_last_query(sql, name, &block)
    @last_query = [sql, name]
    log_without_last_query(sql, name, &block)
  end

end
```

Now you can get the query with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.last_query # => ...
```

Comment: +1 for monkey patching a part of Rails, the king of monkey patching.

Comment: I had to put the call to `alias_method_chain` after the method definition, otherwise it caused the following error: `core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in 'alias_method': undefined method 'log_with_last_query' for class 'ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter' (NameError)`

Answer (score 3):

Probably because I have a newer version of ActiveRecord than when this question was asked, but to get it to work with ActiveRecord 3.2.3 I updated the script of Simone Carletti: I added the extra attribute `binds` and moved the call to `alias_method_chain` below the method definition because otherwise it would raise an error saying that it can't find the method.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter.class_eval do

  attr_reader :last_query

  def log_with_last_query(sql, name, binds=[], &block)
    @last_query = [sql, name]
    log_without_last_query(sql, name, binds, &block)
  end
  alias_method_chain :log, :last_query

end
```

Getting the last query is still the same:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.last_query # => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your development log should include all SQL queries that are run.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the thing -- it has ALL of the queries.  I only want to see what I explicitly log.