# Dump queries made by ActiveRecord to file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there an easy way to dump / write the queries performed by ActiveRecord into a file?
I know that they are in the log, but without parsing that? How can I get the queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer.
[How do I get the last SQL query performed by ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090801/how-do-i-get-the-last-sql-query-performed-by-activerecord-in-ruby-on-rails/1091006#1091006)

You can easily update the method in order to save the queries into a file.