# How do you programmatically inspect the sql generated by active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What's the code to look at the sql an ActiveRecord query is going to produce.  For example, Modelname.all would produce "Select * from modelname".  Is there any method that gives access to that string?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be done through an API, but you can see the generated SQL by looking at development.log, which I suppose you could parse.

Extending this answer, you can provide a custom Logger to ActiveRecord via

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = yourLoggerHere
```

Maybe you can create a Logger that'll do all the work for you. Found [this link](http://www.caboo.se/articles/2008/9/29/a-simple-rails-slow-query-logger) which implements one for detecting slow queries.

Comment: Thanks JRL, I'm actually looking specifically for how its done throug the API.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API method to store the queries executed by ActiveRecord. However, you can hack ActiveRecord, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090801/how-do-i-get-the-last-sql-query-performed-by-activerecord-in-ruby-on-rails/1091006#1091006).