# ActiveRecord includes: How get access to multiple queries resuls that were performed by activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following query that loads associations:

```
contacts = current_user.contacts.includes(:contact_lists).where(id: subscribed_contact_ids)

[DEBUG] Contact Load (2.6ms) SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = 7 AND "contacts"."id" IN (4273, 4275, 4277, 4278, 4281, 4285, 4297, 4305, 4307, 4308, 4315, 4318, 4323, 4326, 4331, 4333, 4344, 4349, 4359, 4361, 4368, 4372, 4373, 4378, 4382, 4389, 4392, 4394, 4404, 4428, 4450, 4469, 4473, 4489, 4490, 4495, 4497, 4498, 4501, 4505, 4514, 4520, 4525, 4536, 4545, 4554, 4555, 4561, 4568, 4572)

[DEBUG] Subscription Load (0.8ms) SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."contact_id" IN (4273, 4275, 4277, 4278, 4281, 4285, 4297, 4305, 4307, 4308, 4315, 4318, 4323, 4326, 4331, 4333, 4344, 4349, 4359, 4361, 4368, 4372, 4373, 4378, 4382, 4389, 4392, 4394, 4404, 4428, 4450, 4469, 4473, 4489, 4490, 4495, 4497, 4498, 4501, 4505, 4514, 4520, 4525, 4536, 4545, 4554, 4555, 4561, 4568, 4572)

[DEBUG] ContactList Load (0.5ms) SELECT "contact_lists".* FROM "contact_lists" WHERE "contact_lists"."id" IN (9, 8)
```

**I also need to get distinct contact_lists, basically i need to load the result of last query separately.**

So the question is: is there way to load these contact lists without running the complex queries again?

The option to iterate through each record to get the contact_lists and then to remove duplicates is not attractive at all.
The other option is to run complex join query again (seems not really good either):

```
contact_list_ids = current_user.subscriptions.select('distinct contact_list_id').where(contact_id: contact_ids).pluck(:contact_list_id)
current_user.contact_lists.where(id: contact_list_ids)
```

Those queries are cached somewhere. Is there way to access the query cache directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem. But it requires you to monkey patch rails which might not be a great idea.

[How do I get the last SQL query performed by ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090801/how-do-i-get-the-last-sql-query-performed-by-activerecord-in-ruby-on-rails)

I would rather iterate over the contacts and store the `contact_lists` in a hash with their id as key. Then you do not need to worry about duplicates

```
contact_lists = {}
contacts.each { |c| c.contact_lists.each { |cl| contact_lists[cl.id] = cl } }
```

or something.

Comment: If I monkey-patch rails the way it's done there it will return query with inner join.

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.last_query
=> ["SELECT \"contact_lists\".* FROM \"contact_lists\" INNER JOIN \"subscriptions\" ON \"subscriptions\".\"contact_list_id\" = \"contact_lists\".\"id\" WHERE \"contact_lists\".\"user_id\" = 7 AND \"subscriptions\".\"contact_id\" IN (3401, 3407, 3410, 3424, 3428, 3430, etc..

Comment: Ah, Sorry about that. I would still think it would be better to avoid that even if it worked though.